# Optimization: Count the number of suffix pairs

Tags: string, algorithm, optimization, suffix, suffix-array

Question: Count the total number of pairs in a list of strings, so that for each pair, one string is the suffix of the other. For example, "door" is the suffix of "backdoor", "a" is the suffix of "cba".

``[1st Version: Slow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eWW6K.png)

```py
def count_same_endings(words):
    """
    Count the number of word pairs with the same ending.

    Parameters:
    words (list): List of words.

    Returns:
    int: The count of word pairs with the same ending.
    """
    strings = sorted([word[::-1] for word in words])
    count = 0
    to_print = []
    i = 0
    while i < len(words):
        j = 1
        while i + j < len(words) and strings[i + j].startswith(strings[i]):
            # to_print.append((strings[i+j][::-1], strings[i][::-1]))
            count += 1
            j += 1
        i += 1
    # print(to_print)
    return count

words = ['cba', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'ba', 'ca']
result = count_same_endings(words)
print(result)
19
```

``[2nd Version: Faster](https://i.stack.imgur.com/igPEh.png)

```py
def count_end_slices(strings):
    slice_count = {}
    strings_count = {}
    count = 0

    # Iterate over each word in the list
    for string in strings:
        length = len(string)

        # Check if this word is already the suffix of some previous words
        if string in slice_count:
            count += slice_count[string]

        # Generate slices that include the end of the string
        for start in range(length):
            slice = string[start:]

            # Count the occurrences of each slice
            if slice in slice_count:
                # Check if previous words are the suffix of this string
                if slice in strings_count:
                    count += strings_count[slice] if slice != string else 0
                slice_count[slice] += 1
            else:
                slice_count[slice] = 1

        # Account for this word
        if string in strings_count:
            strings_count[string] += 1
        else:
            strings_count[string] = 1

    return slice_count, count
```

``[Comparison between 1st and 2nd](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U8PvA.png)

I have already created two algorithms which are both pretty brute force. I wonder if there is a more optimized way of solving this question.

Comment: If you had posted code in text form that I could copy and run, I would have tried to write a faster version.

Comment: [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors)

Comment: @MattTimmermans Hi, sorry, I have made the change.

Answer (score 1):

There is room for improvement, and you can optimize the solution further. Let me provide you with an optimized version based on your 2nd version, addressing some inefficiencies and improving the overall readability:

```
def count_end_slices(strings):
    slice_count = {}
    count = 0

    for string in strings:
        length = len(string)

        # Check if this word is already the suffix of some previous words
        if string in slice_count:
            count += slice_count[string]

        # Generate slices that include the end of the string
        for start in range(1, length):
            slice = string[start:]

            # Count the occurrences of each slice
            if slice in slice_count:
                count += slice_count[slice]

            # Update slice_count
            slice_count[slice] = slice_count.get(slice, 0) + 1

    return count
```

Changes and improvements:

1. Removed the unnecessary strings_count dictionary, as it was not being used for anything useful.
2. Removed the inner loop that iterated over the entire length of the string and started the loop from start = 1 since an empty slice is not useful in this context.
3. Used slice_count.get(slice, 0) + 1 to handle the case where the slice is not in the dictionary yet, avoiding the need for an explicit check.

This optimized version should provide better performance and maintain the correctness of the solution.

Answer (score 0):

We can join all strings with symbol "$" (it is less than all alphabetic symbols) into string `common`, then build **suffix array** over `common` string, I've used [implementation from here](https://louisabraham.github.io/articles/suffix-arrays).

Then sort source strings, and look for every string+"$" in suffix array. Sorted suffixes and sorted strings allow to walk through both arrays once.

When string is larger lexically than current suffix, we move to the next suffix.

When string is equal to current suffix (more exactly, to its prefix of corresponding length), we increment counter and move to the next suffix.

When string is  lexically smaller than current suffix, we move to the next string.

At the end we subtract number of strings from counter (to remove coincidences of strings with themselves).

```
from collections import defaultdict

def sort_bucket(s, bucket, order):
    d = defaultdict(list)
    for i in bucket:
        key = s[i + order // 2:i + order]
        d[key].append(i)
    result = []
    for k, v in sorted(d.items()):
        if len(v) > 1:
            result += sort_bucket(s, v, 2 * order)
        else:
            result.append(v[0])
    return result


def suffix_array_ManberMyers(s):
    return sort_bucket(s, range(len(s)), 1)

strs = ["back", "backdoor", "cba", "ba", "or", "door"]  #4
strs = ['cba', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'ba', 'ba', 'ca']  #25
strs = ['cba', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'ba', 'ca']      #19
strs = ['cba', 'a', 'a', 'ba'] #6
strs = ['cba', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'ba', 'ba', 'ca', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'ba', 'ba', 'ca'] #96
strs = ['dcba', 'cba', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'ba', 'ba', 'ca', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'ba', 'ba', 'ca'] #109


def cnt_suff(strs):
    common = "$".join(strs)+"$"
    print(common)
    sa = suffix_array_ManberMyers(common)
    print(sa)

    lensa = len(sa)
    lenstrs = len(strs)
    strs.sort()
    i = 0
    strcnt = 1
    cnt = 0
    while i < lenstrs-1 and strs[i]==strs[i+1]:
        i += 1
        strcnt += 1
    t = strs[i]+"$"
    cnt -= strcnt*(strcnt+1)//2
    lt = len(t)
    k = 0
    while k < lensa:
        subs = common[sa[k]:sa[k]+lt]
        if t > subs:
            k+=1
        elif t == subs:
            print(subs, strcnt)
            cnt+=strcnt
            k+=1
        else:
            i+=1
            if i==lenstrs:
                break
            strcnt = 1
            while i < lenstrs-1 and strs[i]==strs[i+1]:
                i += 1
                strcnt += 1
            cnt -= strcnt*(strcnt+1)//2
            t = strs[i] + "$"
            lt = len(t)
    return (cnt)

def dumb(strs:list[str]):
    c = 0
    for i in range(len(strs)-1):
        for j in range(i+1, len(strs)):
            if strs[i].endswith(strs[j]) or strs[j].endswith(strs[i]):
                c += 1
    return c

print(cnt_suff(strs), dumb(strs))
```

Comment: Hi, although this algorithm looks good and efficient, I'm afraid it is not correct in all cases, for the case ['cba', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'ba', 'ca'], it should return 19.

Comment: 25 is still not the correct answer. For example, an input of ['cba', 'a', 'a', 'ba']:  

`When 'cba' comes in, it is neither a suffix of anything, so count stays 0.  `
When 'a' comes in, it is the suffix of 'cba', so the count increases to 1.  
When the second 'a' comes in, it is the suffix of 'cba' and the first 'a', so count increases to 3.  
When 'ba' comes in, it is the suffix of 'cba', and also the two 'a's are its suffix as well, so the count increases to 6.

Comment: Aha, I counted `a-a` and similar pairs twice. Added correction.  Results are similar to dumb function `if strs[i].endswith(strs[j]) or strs[j].endswith(strs[i]):` for some tests

Comment: Hi, thank you very much for the updated version. It correctly outputs the expected outputs now, with an average time of 2.4s per 100,000 strings.

Comment: @Specter43 For my set of random strings this code was slightly slower than nice_dev Trie approach.  Suffix_array construction takes 80% of time, so good implementation of it might help. Also if there is a lot of duplicate strings, they might be "packed", but algo should become more complex.

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of ways to solve this problem in linear time, but in python, performance is often about leveraging the fast built-ins instead of executing slow python code.

Your fast implementation is pretty fast, I think.  I came up with a few versions that were a little faster, but none that were a lot faster.

Of the ones that were a little faster, this one is the simplest.  It runs a little faster than yours (using my test data) even though it includes an O(n log n) sort:

```python
def fast(strings):
    #reverse all the strings to turn suffixes into prefixes
    sorted = [s[::-1] for s in strings]
    sorted.sort()
    # a prefix that matches i characters in the previous
    # string matches matchCounts[i-1] words
    matchCounts = []
    prevstr = ''
    count = 0
    for s in sorted:
        for i in range(min(len(prevstr), len(s))):
            if s[i] != prevstr[i]:
                del matchCounts[i:]
                break
            count+=matchCounts[i]
        while len(matchCounts) < len(s):
            matchCounts.append(0)
        matchCounts[len(s)-1] += 1
        prevstr = s
    return count
```

This is a somewhat optimized version of your algorithm that runs a little faster than both of them:

```python
def faster(strings):
    suffixIds = {}
    counts = [0]
    wordcounts = [0]
    wordids = []
    for s in strings:
        id = 0
        for i in range(len(s)-1, -1, -1):
            key = s[i:]
            id = suffixIds.get(key)
            if id == None:
                id = len(counts)
                counts.append(1)
                wordcounts.append(0)
                suffixIds[key] = id
            else:
                counts[id] += 1
        wordids.append(id)
        wordcounts[id] += 1
    return sum([counts[id] for id in wordids]) - sum([n * (n+1) // 2 for n in wordcounts])
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer! These two are great algorithms, and they are indeed a little faster than mine. Under my setup, Mine takes 0.4 seconds on average and yours takes 0.28 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

Mine is a [`Trie`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie) version to store the strings. We store the strings in a reversed form along with a `cnt` for each node indicating the no. of strings that ended at this node acting as a suffix for the current string at hand.

While counting, we also maintain a set for not including duplicate pairs for duplicate strings.

**Snippet:**

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self, val):
        self.val = val
        self.kids = dict()
        self.cnt = 0
        
def countSuffixPairs(words):
    for i in range(len(words)):
        words[i] = words[i][::-1] # reverse all for suffixes
    def insertInTrie(root, s):
        temp = root
        for i in range(len(s)):
            if s[i] not in temp.kids:
                temp.kids[ s[i] ] = Node(s[i])
            temp = temp.kids[ s[i] ]
        temp.cnt += 1
    def countPairsInTrie(root, s, fullWordIncluded):
        temp = root
        cnt = 0
        for i in range(len(s)):
            if s[i] not in temp.kids:
                break
            temp = temp.kids[ s[i] ]
            if i == len(s) - 1:
               if s not in fullWordIncluded:
                   fullWordIncluded.add(s)
                   cnt += (temp.cnt * (temp.cnt - 1)) // 2
            else:
                cnt += temp.cnt                   
        return cnt
    root = Node('~')
    for word in words: 
        insertInTrie(root, word)
    ans = 0
    fullWordIncluded = set()
    for word in words: 
        ans += countPairsInTrie(root, word, fullWordIncluded)
    return ans


print(countSuffixPairs(['cba', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'ba', 'ca'])) // 19
```

[**Live Online Demo**](https://onecompiler.com/python/3zuwc7apv)

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer, and yes, I have tried using Trie, which was really, in my mind, how this question was designed to be solved. And it is indeed that your Trie implementation is the fastest among my previous trials. However, under mass testing, it takes on average 2.8s to finish a 100,000-string input, which is slower, and it over-counts sometimes for some reason that I haven't understood.

Comment: @Specter43 It should never over count. Can you give a reasonable small test case that I can check at my end? The avg. Time of 2.8 s might be because of the dict() implementation I believe.

Comment: I apologize, upon further testing, your function is actually correct, one my previous testing version modifies the original input, and that caused some differences.